# Целесообразно ли использовать Core Data для приложения заметок iOS?

Tags: swift

Являясь нубом в программировании открыл для себя Swift (походу дела изучаю этот язык). Для практики решил сделать небольшое приложение для заметок, где они будут сохраняться на телефоне. При создании проекта встал в ступор, нужно ли использовать Core Data для сохранения этих заметок? Или же существуют другие, более подходящие решения. Так как порывшись немного на различных ресурсах, люди говорят что Core Data предназначен для больших объемов данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отлично подходит. Про большие объёмы данных, видимо имелось ввиду по сравнению с UserDefault, где вообще хранят мизер, например настройки программы, или в играх, например, список лидеров и свои баллы.

Comment: Благодарю Вас =)

Answer (score 0):

Вполне подходит.

Хотя лично я был предпочел [RealM](https://realm.io/products/realm-database), для таких задач его использовать заметно проще.